# Can I have two values link together in HashSet?

Tags: java

So currently I am connected to a database table in java.

```
  this.senders = new HashSet();
  this.receiver = new HashSet();
  while (rs.next()) {
    this.senders.add(new MailAddress(rs.getString("senderEmail")));
    this.receiver.add(new MailAddress(rs.getString("receiverEmail")));
  }
```

Below my codes will compare

```
if (this.receiver.equals(mail.getRecipients()) && this.senders.contains(mail.getSender())) {
  return mail.getRecipients();
}
```

But I kinda feel like is it comparing the correct values in the correct column?

So for example the first column is user1 and second column is user2.
then as follows, user2 and user3, user3 and user1.

So if this.receiver is equals to user1 and this.sender containers user2, i will return it. But I have no idea if it is comparing row by row or iterating through the receiver/sender hashset or not. Should i include a iterator below ?

Comment: There are no columns (or rows, for that matter) in Java outside of database applications and 2D arrays. There are elements of a set which are objects of some type, and there are fields of an object. Look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html#equals-java.lang.Object-

Comment: You can iterate through your HashSet and compare the objects using any field you want. Not sure how db is related here.

Comment: @yogidilip `rs` in the first example must be `ResultSet`. It does not make the question any easier to understand, though.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yaap, I know rs is resultset. I was wondering what's the confusion around it :)

Comment: So if I iterate through this.receiver and this.sender does it compare the first values or does it just go through all the values in both receiver and sender?